# LWC imperative call in JS is not connecting with the Apex method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

The JS in my LWC is showing it has data in the params I'm passing from JS to my Apex method. The Apex method doesn't seem to be connection though.

Apex
Note: in Dev Console, in the log, these debug statements never print. The logs do show:
CODE_UNIT_STARTED[EXTERNAL]|apex://RfqSendVendorEmailsController/ACTION$insertJunctionRecords

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String insertJunctionRecords(String[] accountIDs, ID rfqID){

    System.debug('*** insertJunctionRecords accountIDs: ' + accountIDs);
    List<VendorRFQ__c> junctionRecords = new List<VendorRFQ__c>();

    for(ID id : accountIDs) {
        VendorRFQ__c vRfq = new VendorRFQ__c(Vendor__c = id, Request_for_Quote__c = rfqID);
        junctionRecords.add(vRfq);
    }

    System.debug('*** junctionRecords: ' + junctionRecords);
    try {
        insert junctionRecords;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }

    return 'Emails have been sent.';
}
```

Javascript
Note: the console logs show there is data for both variables. this.vendorsSelected is an array

```
handleClickSendEmails(event) {
        var vendorsStringified = JSON.stringify(this.vendorsSelected);
        console.log('*** vendorsStringified: ' + vendorsStringified);

    
    var vendorsSelectedIds = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.vendorsSelected.length; i++) {
        console.log('*** this.vendorsSelected[i].value: ' + vendorsStringified);
        vendorsSelectedIds.push(this.vendorsSelected[i].value);
    }
    
    console.log('*** vendorsSelectedIds: ' + vendorsSelectedIds);

    if (vendorsSelectedIds) {
        insertJunctionRecords({accountIDs : vendorsSelectedIds, 
                            rfqID : this.recordId})
            .then(results => {
                    console.log('*** results: ' + results);

                    this.sendEmailsMessage(results);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                });
    } else {
        console.log('*** vendorsSelectedIds was empty');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `this.vendorsSelected` show in the debug log? How is it set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `String accountIDs`.

You can't iterate a string.

It needs to be a list in the Apex method.

**Either** pass in an Array in the javascript code and recieve a `String[] accountIDs`

**Or** pass the string, receive `String accountIDs`
and parse it to a list

```
Id[] IDs = (Id[])JSON.deserialize(accountIDs,Id[].class);
```

Prior to calling `insertJunctionRecords` , send just the ids after extracting them:

```
let vendorIds = this.vendorsSelected.map( vendor => { vendor.value});
//assuming that is a property on the vendor object
```

Comment: Thanks Caspar. I went with your first option, but same result as before. I've updated my main post with my latest code.

Comment: In JS, vendorsSelected is an array

Comment: Actually, I'm realizing it's an array of objects... hmm

Comment: I think all I need to do is convert this Object array to ID array. My first attempt at doing this with a JS loop didn't work....[{"value":"0013k00003C7AQsAAN","label":"Car","isVisible":true,"selected":true},{"value":"0013k00002xs223AAA","label":"CGI","isVisible":true,"selected":true}]

Comment: I updated original post, JS code now has a loop to extract "value" to an ID array

Comment: Ah, ok. I got it working with standard loop. That said, I'd like to understand the map, so I tried this, but it didn't work....           let vendorsSelectedIds = this.vendorsSelected.map( vendor => { vendor.value});

Comment: vendor here is a just some kind of on the fly variable? It doesn't need instantiation anywhere in my js file?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the **insertJunctionRecords** method in your Apex code is not being called from the JavaScript code. This could be because of several reasons:

The **insertJunctionRecords** method might not be marked as **@AuraEnabled**, which is necessary for it to be callable from the JavaScript code.
The method might not be static, which is necessary for it to be callable from the JavaScript code.
The method might not be in a controller class, which is necessary for it to be callable from the JavaScript code.
To fix this issue, make sure that the **insertJunctionRecords** method is marked as **@AuraEnabled**, is static, and is in a controller class.

Here's an example of how the **insertJunctionRecords** method might look like after making these changes:

```
public with sharing class RfqSendVendorEmailsController {

@AuraEnabled
public static String insertJunctionRecords(String[] accountIDs, ID rfqID){
    System.debug('*** insertJunctionRecords accountIDs: ' + accountIDs);
    List<VendorRFQ__c> junctionRecords = new List<VendorRFQ__c>();

    for(ID id : accountIDs) {
        VendorRFQ__c vRfq = new VendorRFQ__c(Vendor__c = id, Request_for_Quote__c = rfqID);
        junctionRecords.add(vRfq);
    }

    System.debug('*** junctionRecords: ' + junctionRecords);
    try {
        insert junctionRecords;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }

    return 'Emails have been sent.';
}
```

Once the **insertJunctionRecords** method is callable from the JavaScript code, you should see the debug statements in the method print in the log in the Developer Console.